# Access Docker container file system via an UNC share on the host machine

Tags: docker, devops, samba, windows-server

Due to our special system design, the database consists of both the SQL server and the file system (e.g. the SQL server stores the path to the file system, and the client directly access to file system to get the static data). And now I am trying to containerize the whole "package". Would it be possible to do the following with Docker:

- Create a static data directory inside Docker container
- Create an UNC share on the host that points to that static data directory
- When the container is killed, that static data directory is gone too (I can handle removing the share from the host later on)

I want the static data to follow the life cycle of the container (it comes and goes with the container), thus mounting is not an option (or is it?)

Or what I am trying to do is insane and I should start from scratch? Thanks! :)